# Passing variables to a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a web application based on Dark Sky API which gets the forecast about a location. I would like to show the data I have collected from the API in a bootstrap modal but I don't know how to pass the javascript global variables that I have defined for temperature, humidity, etc...

I'm gonna display here the function where I get the data from the API:

```
function temperature() {
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/{mykey}" + latMark + "," + lngMark + "?units=ca",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (parsed_json) {
                        temperature = Math.round(parsed_json.currently.temperature);
                        summary = parsed_json.currently.summary;
                        humidity = parsed_json.currently.humidity * 100;
                        icon = parsed_json.currently.icon;
                    },
                    error: function (parsed_json) {
                        console.log("Error adding the temperature.");
                    }

                });
            });
```

And this is my modal right now which is based in a template I got from bootstrap but will help you answer this question

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Weather Information</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body text-center">
                    <p id="output"></p><br>
                    <canvas id="icons" class="icon" width="128" height="128"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I was looking to do something in the body of the modal like the following example:

```
The temperature is: + variable + ºC;
The humidity is: + variable*100 + %;
The summary is: + variable;
```

Thanks in advance for the help :D

Comment: Can you not just use some jQuery to put the contents inside the modal? E.g. `$('#output').html('The temperature is: ' + variable + 'ºC');`

Comment: You are right @putvande. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the variables content to output id on ajax success, it will render the variables into HTML.
Also, jQuery append supports the HTML, you can add according to your wish. more details [see here](https://api.jquery.com/append/).

````js
function temperature() {
  $.ajax({
    url:
      "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/{mykey}" +
      latMark +
      "," +
      lngMark +
      "?units=ca",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(parsed_json) {
      temperature = Math.round(parsed_json.currently.temperature);
      summary = parsed_json.currently.summary;
      humidity = parsed_json.currently.humidity * 100;
      icon = parsed_json.currently.icon;
      jQuery("#output").append("The temperature is: " + variable + "ºC");
      jQuery("#output").append("The humidity is:: " + humidity + "%");
      jQuery("#output").append("The summary is: " + summary);
    },
    error: function(parsed_json) {
      console.log("Error adding the temperature.");
    }
  });
}```
````

Comment: Thank you very much. That was it, sorry if it was a stupid question, but it's my first time working with html, javascript and css.

Comment: Don't be Sorry, Question is the first step of learning, Thanks